Failed to run listener function (error: name 'ts' is not defined)
I am currently building a chatbot using Python and Slack API. I am consistently running into the error,

Failed to run listener function (error: name 'ts' is not defined)

I know this is a direct indication that the variable ts is being used but, has not been defined in the current scope of my code.
ts is being used in my response function, but I don't know where it should be defined prior to the parameter of the response function in the scope of my code.
The listener function below, is listening for the command '/help'. I am unsure of where 'ts' should be inserted within the parameters of this function.
@app.command('/help')
# after the command is placed, the option menu should appear
# you need to grab the ts value of one of these message objects
def message_hello(ack, respond, body, command):  # add body for parameter testing (ack, respond,body, command)
    # pprint(body)
    ack()
    # def message_hello(message, say):
    # channel_id = message['channel']
    channel_id = command['channel_id']  # replace command with body if necessary
    # user = message['user']
    user = command['user_id']  # replace command with body if necessary
    # greeting message to user upon inserted question it it-helpdesk channel
    hello_text = f'Hi <@{user}> *Please select an option from the dropdown menu that best relates to your inquiry.*'
    # say(text=hello_text, channel=channel_id, thread_ts=message['ts'])
    time.sleep(1)

Here, I am checking to see if ts exists within the command dictionary before using it, else print if not. Of course, confirming that it is not present, but I don't know where it should be placed to retrieve the message's ts. Please help! :(
# Checking to see if the 'ts' key exists in the command dictionary before using it
    thread_ts = command.get('ts', None)

    # Calling the 'respond' function with appropriate arguments
    if thread_ts is not None:
        (respond(blocks=blocks, channel=channel_id, thread_ts=thread_ts))
    else:
        pprint("'ts' key not found in command dictionary.")
    # say(text=hello_text, channel=channel_id, thread_ts=message['ts'])
    # ts = command['ts']
    pprint(respond(blocks=blocks, channel=channel_id, thread_ts=ts))  # passing 'ts' # command['ts']


Welcome Geena, is usually recommended here to provide a minimum reproducible example in plain text (you can give it code format or some member will do it for you), so it's easier to reproduce. Anyhow maybe there is someone who can write the whole code and help you out either way. The more you facilitate others, the more you'll get (imo).

I don't know about slack API, just have some basic knowledge on Telegram bot, which apparently looks similar. I would make my contribution deriving from those similarties. I would research about declaring 'ts' as channel_id and user. I don't know if all that information is inside 'command' or inside 'body' (sometimes ts is used as the abbreviation of timestamp). Something like this: channel_id = body['channel_id'] user_id = body['user_id'] ts = body['ts']

thread_ts=ts should probably be thread_ts=thread_ts. That's the name of the variable you assigned from the dictionary lookup.

You should also only call respond() in the if block that checks that the dictionary element exists.
